# Deploying Mock Services as WAR Files by Maven

Tags: soapui

I designed a project to call web service on SOAP UI studio 5.0.0, I could deploy as a war file to deploy on tomcat server but I couldn't build a war by maven. Can you help me design a pom.xml and build it, or other way ?

Comment: Deploy as war might use a utility present under SOAPUI_HOME/bin directory. So you may call the same utility from where ever you wanted to call and provide the appropriate input values.

Comment: As you may understand, SO is not a coding service. You should try doing something by yourself first and then, if you encounter a specific problem, post it so we can assist you. Nevertheless, as a starting point, you could take a look at [Maven's WAR Plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).